# return multidimensional JSON from mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get a list of temperature data from my MYSQL database.

data format is like:

```
masterid - beerline - temperature - temperaturetime 
4000       1              20        2018-02-12 15:59
4000       1              22        2018-02-12 16:59
4001       1              20        2018-02-12 15:59
4001       1              22        2018-02-12 16:59
4002       1              20        2018-02-12 15:59
4002       1              22        2018-02-12 16:59
```

what i would like to do is group these into JSON arrays by the masterid

so i would here get 3 different arrays that i can return with the same JSON output.

it would look something like (i know this is not correct but need some help)

```
    {"4000":{"date":"2018-02-12 15:59","beerline":"1","temperature":"20"},
             {"date":"2018-02-12 16:59","beerline":"1","temperature":"22"}
   },{"4001":{"date":"2018-02-12 15:59","beerline":"1","temperature":"20"},
             {"date":"2018-02-12 16:59","beerline":"1","temperature":"22"}
   },{"4002":{"date":"2018-02-12 15:59","beerline":"1","temperature":"20"},
             {"date":"2018-02-12 16:59","beerline":"1","temperature":"22"}
    }
```

I tried doing:

```
$json = array();

// prepare and bind
        $stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT MasterID,beerline, temperature, temperaturetime       
        FROM temperatures
        WHERE temperatures.MasterID IN (SELECT masterdata.masterNo FROM masterdata WHERE masterdata.customerNo = ?)
        AND temperaturetime BETWEEN DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 DAY) AND NOW()
        ORDER BY MasterID,temperaturetime DESC");
        $stmt->bind_param("s",$customerID);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($masterid, $beerline, $temperature, $temperaturetime);   

        while ($stmt->fetch()) {                
            $json[$masterid] = array(   
            'date' => $temperaturetime,
            'volume' => $beerline,  
            'value' => $temperature                             
            );          
        }
```

This almost works, but clearly only giving me 1 entre for each master: (just ran so not same data)

```
{"4018":{"date":"2018-02-12 08:59:40","volume":14,"value":22.5},"4019":{"date":"2018-02-12 08:59:36","volume":14,"value":22},"4020":{"date":"2018-02-12 08:59:33","volume":14,"value":22},"4021":{"date":"2018-02-12 09:01:26","volume":14,"value":22.5}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just replace

```
$json[$masterid] = array(
```

to

```
$json[$masterid][] = array(
```

Comment: Went with this, super happy you fixed it and yet disapointed i could not see it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
while ($stmt->fetch()) {                
            $json[$masterid] = array(   
            'date' => $temperaturetime,
            'volume' => $beerline,  
            'value' => $temperature                             
            );          
        }
```

Modify your above php code like below :

```
while ($stmt->fetch()) { 

     if( !isset($json[$masterid]) )
         $json[$masterid] = array();

     $json[$masterid][] = array(   
             'date' => $temperaturetime,
             'volume' => $beerline,  
             'value' => $temperature                             
     );          
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer. Too long for a comment...

FWIW, I find this easier to read:

```
SELECT t.MasterID
     , t.beerline
     , t.temperature
     , t.temperaturetime
  FROM temperatures t
  JOIN masterdata m
    ON m.masterno = t.masterid
 WHERE m.customerNo = ?
   AND t.temperaturetime BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY AND NOW()
 ORDER 
    BY t.MasterID
     , t.temperaturetime DESC
```

This sounds like incredibly important work by the way

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, it looks much more clean!